# Is there a CSS property that pushes elements aside (except for margin)?

Tags: html, css

To my container of 200x200px, I have added 10% margin right, in which I believe the contents below it in my html would be pushed outside of the margin area right, yet in my code, contents are not pushed away (below) from my container even though I have placed a margin around all sides of the container.

How come there are elements still overlapping with my container even though I have the container margin in place? Would I only be able to solve solve this by doing multiple br's in my html?? Or is there an actual CSS approach to solve this problem?

I would really appreciate the help on this one, thanks so much!

```css
body {
  color: black;
  background-color: rgb(240, 240, 240);
  margin: 1%;
}

.container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  outline: red solid 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: absolute;
  top: 165%;
  margin: 10%;
  background-image: url(ezio.jpg);
}

.textbox1 {
  width: 40%;
  left: 2%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  outline: red solid 5px;
  background-color: cyan;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 10px;
  border-style: dotted;
  position: relative;
}

.textbox2 {
  width: 40%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  outline: red solid 5px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 45%;
  top: 18%;
  background-color: darkkhaki;
}

.textbox3 {
  width: 40%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  outline: red solid 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
  left: 10%;
}

.textbox4 {
  width: 40%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  outline: red solid 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: absolute;
  left: 55%;
  top: 70%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container"></div>
<div class="textbox1">
  <p> ding Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Molestiae aliquid ea, numquam quod saepe excepturi eaque debitis repellat, quibusdam ratione atque, mollitia ipsum repellendus. Nostrum at possimus fugiat dolores excepturi!</p>
</div>
<br>
<div class="textbox2">
  kingen simp Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Aliquid eum excepturi veritatis officia iusto cum reprehenderit corrupti accusamus, accusantium sequi nobis ab nesciunt quibusdam natus tenetur at enim ipsum magni?</div>
<br>
<div class="textbox3">
  <h4>amazin</h4>
  <p>pie Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Molestiae aliquid ea, numquam quod saepe excepturi eaque debitis repellat, quibusdam ratione atque, mollitia ipsum repellendus. Nostrum at possimus fugiat dolores excepturi!</p>
</div>
<br>
<div class="textbox4">
  <h6>water</h6>
  <p> indigo sill Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Molestiae aliquid ea, numquam quod saepe excepturi eaque debitis repellat, quibusdam ratione atque, mollitia ipsum repellendus. Nostrum at possimus fugiat dolores excepturi!</p>
</div>
<div class="categories">
  <h5>
    categories
    </h2>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">juice</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">grapes</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">mango</a></li>
      <li><a href="test.html">fish</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>name</th>
      <th>age</th>
      <th>email</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>kano minto</td>
      <td>56</td>
      <td>minto@gmail.com</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>heni smio</td>
      <td>24</td>
      <td>dkeo@gmail.com</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>elise trum</td>
      <td>35</td>
      <td>trm@gmail.com</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<br>
```

Comment: Try removing `position: absolute; top: 165% `

Comment: @Yadab I unfortunately can't, I need the position absolute there so that I can position it where ever I want to on the page, and the top 165% is to push it down

Answer (score 0):

In position relative , the element is positioned relative to itself. However, an absolutely positioned element is relative to its parent. An element with position: absolute is removed from the normal document flow. It is positioned automatically to the starting point (top-left corner) of its parent element.

Other than texbox1 all elements are sort of in absolute position, thus have broken free from how documented would have normally flowed them. one after another.

suppose we take away position relative from the textbox1. textbox1 should have been on top of green box but since flow is broken it is considered as if it was the first element in usual scheme of things.
example below.

```css
body {
  color: black;
  background-color: rgb(240, 240, 240);
  margin: 10%;
}

.container{ 
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    outline: green solid 5px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    position: absolute;
    top: 16%;
    margin: 10%;
    background-image: url(ezio.jpg);
}

.textbox1 {
  width: 40%;
  box-sizing: border-box; 
  outline: red solid 5px; 
  background-color: cyan;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 10px; 
  border-style: dotted;
  
}

.textbox2 {
  width: 40%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  outline: red solid 5px;
  position: absolute; 
  left: 45%; 
  top: 18%;

  background-color: darkkhaki;
}

.textbox3 {
  width: 40%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  outline: red solid 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
  left: 10%;
}

.textbox4 {
  width: 40%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  outline: red solid 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: absolute;
  left: 55%;
  top: 70%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> 

    <title>GamerHub</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="C:/Users/zeren/CSS/newcssgamerhub.css" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
  
<div class="container"></div>

<div class="textbox1"> 
<p> ding Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Molestiae aliquid ea, numquam quod saepe excepturi eaque debitis repellat,
     quibusdam ratione atque, mollitia ipsum repellendus. Nostrum at possimus fugiat dolores excepturi!</p>
</div>

<br>

<div class="textbox2">
        
    kingen simp Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Aliquid eum excepturi veritatis officia iusto cum reprehenderit corrupti accusamus, accusantium sequi nobis ab nesciunt quibusdam natus tenetur at enim ipsum magni?</div>

    <br>
    
    <div class="textbox3"> 
        <h4>amazin</h4>
        <p>pie Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Molestiae aliquid ea, numquam quod saepe excepturi eaque debitis repellat,
             quibusdam ratione atque, mollitia ipsum repellendus. Nostrum at possimus fugiat dolores excepturi!</p>
        </div>
        
        <br>

        <div class="textbox4"> 
            <h6>water</h6>
            <p> indigo sill Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Molestiae aliquid ea, numquam quod saepe excepturi eaque debitis repellat,
                 quibusdam ratione atque, mollitia ipsum repellendus. Nostrum at possimus fugiat dolores excepturi!</p>
            </div>

        <div class="categories">
            <h5>
                categories
            </h2>
            <ul>
            <li><a href="#">juice</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">grapes</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">mango</a></li>
            <li><a href="test.html">fish</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
 
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
<th>name</th>
<th>age</th>
<th>email</th>

</tr>

            </thead>
                      
            <tbody>
                <tr>
<td>kano minto</td>
<td>56</td>
<td>minto@gmail.com</td>

                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>heni smio</td>
                    <td>24</td>
                    <td>dkeo@gmail.com</td>
                                        
                                    </tr>

                                    <tr>
                                        <td>elise trum</td>
                                        <td>35</td>
                                        <td>trm@gmail.com</td>
                                                                                
                                                        </tr>

            </tbody>
        </table>
        
        <br>
</body>
```

when we reapply position relative to the textbox1 it flows according to the stacking placement in code. after container.
example below;

```css
body {
  color: black;
  background-color: rgb(240, 240, 240);
  margin: 10%;
}

.container{ 
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    outline: green solid 5px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    position: absolute;
    top: 16%;
    margin: 10%;
    background-image: url(ezio.jpg);
}

.textbox1 {
  width: 40%;
    position: relative;
 
  box-sizing: border-box; 
  outline: red solid 5px; 
  background-color: cyan;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 10px; 
  border-style: dotted;
  
}

.textbox2 {
  width: 40%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  outline: red solid 5px;
  position: absolute; 
  left: 45%; 
  top: 18%;

  background-color: darkkhaki;
}

.textbox3 {
  width: 40%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  outline: red solid 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
  left: 10%;
}

.textbox4 {
  width: 40%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  outline: red solid 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: absolute;
  left: 55%;
  top: 70%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> 

    <title>GamerHub</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="C:/Users/zeren/CSS/newcssgamerhub.css" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
  
<div class="container"></div>

<div class="textbox1"> 
<p> ding Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Molestiae aliquid ea, numquam quod saepe excepturi eaque debitis repellat,
     quibusdam ratione atque, mollitia ipsum repellendus. Nostrum at possimus fugiat dolores excepturi!</p>
</div>

<br>

<div class="textbox2">
        
    kingen simp Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Aliquid eum excepturi veritatis officia iusto cum reprehenderit corrupti accusamus, accusantium sequi nobis ab nesciunt quibusdam natus tenetur at enim ipsum magni?</div>

    <br>
    
    <div class="textbox3"> 
        <h4>amazin</h4>
        <p>pie Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Molestiae aliquid ea, numquam quod saepe excepturi eaque debitis repellat,
             quibusdam ratione atque, mollitia ipsum repellendus. Nostrum at possimus fugiat dolores excepturi!</p>
        </div>
        
        <br>

        <div class="textbox4"> 
            <h6>water</h6>
            <p> indigo sill Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Molestiae aliquid ea, numquam quod saepe excepturi eaque debitis repellat,
                 quibusdam ratione atque, mollitia ipsum repellendus. Nostrum at possimus fugiat dolores excepturi!</p>
            </div>

        <div class="categories">
            <h5>
                categories
            </h2>
            <ul>
            <li><a href="#">juice</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">grapes</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">mango</a></li>
            <li><a href="test.html">fish</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
 
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
<th>name</th>
<th>age</th>
<th>email</th>

</tr>

            </thead>
                      
            <tbody>
                <tr>
<td>kano minto</td>
<td>56</td>
<td>minto@gmail.com</td>

                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>heni smio</td>
                    <td>24</td>
                    <td>dkeo@gmail.com</td>
                                        
                                    </tr>

                                    <tr>
                                        <td>elise trum</td>
                                        <td>35</td>
                                        <td>trm@gmail.com</td>
                                                                                
                                                        </tr>

            </tbody>
        </table>
        
        <br>
</body>
```

on the same note if one is to take away position relative absolute of container then leave everything intact then textbox1 will start from the last boundary of container rest will break flow and place them self according to them self.

```css
body {
  color: black;
  background-color: rgb(240, 240, 240);
  margin: 10%;
}

.container{ 
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    outline: green solid 5px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  
    top: 16%;
    margin: 10%;
    background-image: url(ezio.jpg);
}

.textbox1 {
  width: 40%;
    position: relative;
 
  box-sizing: border-box; 
  outline: red solid 5px; 
  background-color: cyan;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 10px; 
  border-style: dotted;
  
}

.textbox2 {
  width: 40%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  outline: red solid 5px;
  position: absolute; 
  left: 45%; 
  top: 18%;

  background-color: darkkhaki;
}

.textbox3 {
  width: 40%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  outline: red solid 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
  left: 10%;
}

.textbox4 {
  width: 40%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  outline: red solid 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: absolute;
  left: 55%;
  top: 70%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> 

    <title>GamerHub</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="C:/Users/zeren/CSS/newcssgamerhub.css" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
  
<div class="container"></div>

<div class="textbox1"> 
<p> ding Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Molestiae aliquid ea, numquam quod saepe excepturi eaque debitis repellat,
     quibusdam ratione atque, mollitia ipsum repellendus. Nostrum at possimus fugiat dolores excepturi!</p>
</div>

<br>

<div class="textbox2">
        
    kingen simp Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Aliquid eum excepturi veritatis officia iusto cum reprehenderit corrupti accusamus, accusantium sequi nobis ab nesciunt quibusdam natus tenetur at enim ipsum magni?</div>

    <br>
    
    <div class="textbox3"> 
        <h4>amazin</h4>
        <p>pie Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Molestiae aliquid ea, numquam quod saepe excepturi eaque debitis repellat,
             quibusdam ratione atque, mollitia ipsum repellendus. Nostrum at possimus fugiat dolores excepturi!</p>
        </div>
        
        <br>

        <div class="textbox4"> 
            <h6>water</h6>
            <p> indigo sill Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Molestiae aliquid ea, numquam quod saepe excepturi eaque debitis repellat,
                 quibusdam ratione atque, mollitia ipsum repellendus. Nostrum at possimus fugiat dolores excepturi!</p>
            </div>

        <div class="categories">
            <h5>
                categories
            </h2>
            <ul>
            <li><a href="#">juice</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">grapes</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">mango</a></li>
            <li><a href="test.html">fish</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
 
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
<th>name</th>
<th>age</th>
<th>email</th>

</tr>

            </thead>
                      
            <tbody>
                <tr>
<td>kano minto</td>
<td>56</td>
<td>minto@gmail.com</td>

                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>heni smio</td>
                    <td>24</td>
                    <td>dkeo@gmail.com</td>
                                        
                                    </tr>

                                    <tr>
                                        <td>elise trum</td>
                                        <td>35</td>
                                        <td>trm@gmail.com</td>
                                                                                
                                                        </tr>

            </tbody>
        </table>
        
        <br>
</body>
```

So I guess all boxes are behaving according to what ever behaving according to programming guidelines but require fine tuning until desired result is achieved.

ave visit at this site, it uses CSS positioning to achieve the Visual effect.[enter link description here](https://brixbon.com/welcome)

Comment: No sorry, this doesnt address the problem. Im not trying to enclose EVERYTHING around the container. Im specifically interested in why the margin around the container in my code doesnt affect the content below it on the page i.e that the elements should go below it. For the record, to clear up, in my full code i have an img within the container, but that doesnt necessarily change the premises of the question

Comment: Lets work on this I have popped up an image in the container so visual could grasp what was going on.

Comment: I am assuming that container need to be body has margin of 1% .... thus container and rest of textboxs will start off from that.  then container being the first element starts of from 160px margin on top position. rest of the elements after aka below are on relative position so are taking trigger from what ever container computes to.

Comment: unlike textbox2 which is absolute position thus does not bother with what  container computes to it will have its own compute paint. but text box one is relative so it takes top position being the end of container and what ever you give to left will apply.  I am going to exampelify with some example then take your hint from there.

Comment: Right, so i played around a bit with the html order of elements and relative/absolute positions, and my findings was that with absolute, it doesnt apply its margin on other elements pushing them aside. And with html, the position of elements is critical for where you want them to end up in the document. the latter finding felt very noob-like, but im happy that i managed to resolve this with some experimentation, thank you for your input :)

Comment: I am glad it helped. Tbh its always idea+trials+refresh button to get to the visual one needs to get.